# Temporal Correlation in R

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

Having used stack overflow for years without signing up I now truly need some help!

My data consists of samples collected from the same location in three different streams between 2012-2014. The data collected includes continuous phosphorus, nitrate and suspended sediment measures. Rainfall data from the area has also been downloaded.

The samples for each parameter have been taken daily although there are holes in the data set so I am guessing I cannot call these regularly spaced data points. I was simply modelling using lme on log transformed data, although this was causing NaNs. I then realised I needed to incorporate temporal correlation at each site due to the daily auto-correlation and not just produce a nested design.

Having spend two days working through error msgs resulting from using templates in "Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R", I am still unsure which design to use for the data I've collected.

Advice would be welcomed on the design my model should be taking....thank you!

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! There are several problems here: first, you need to post some data (See here how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Some days will have rainfall = 0, so log(0) is not good. Also, there are packages that can automatically interpolate the missing points for you.

Comment: Tweddie distributions are often being used for rainfall data (they are defined for the set of positive reals but with a point mass on zero). Other approaches include a two-stage model; a binary model to model probability of rainfall and then a truncated count model for the amount of rainfall, which only kicks in if a day is predicted to have rainfall given the data. The Tweedie of a Gamma distribution could be used for the other continuous data too.

Comment: @user3511094, if you care to identify yourself, feel free to contact me off list (see email address in my profile) as I have been doing these sorts of models recently.